# Using Java 8 Streams to accomplish removing loops

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of documents objects that need to be mapped based on certain criteria. There is a utility function that takes any 2 document types and determines if they match on a number of criteria, like genre of document, whether they share any authors etc. The code works but I';d like to use Java Streams to solve it if possible.

I currently solve this by using the following code:

```
  class Document{
     private String genre;
     private List<Author> authors;
     private String isbn;
     private boolean paperBack;
     ...
  }
```

I also use a library utility that has a function that returns true given a series of matching criteria and a pair of documents. It simply returns a boolean.

```
   boolean matchesOnCriteria(Document doc1, Document doc2, Criteria criteria){
       ...
   }
```

Here is the matching code for finding the books that match on the provided criteria

```
     DocumentUtils utils = DocumentUitls.instance();
     Criteria userCriteria = ...
     List<Pair> matches = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Document> documents = entityManager.findBy(.....);

   for(Document doc1 : documents){
      for(Documents doc2 : documents){
         if(!doc1.equals(doc2){
             if (utils.matchesOnCriteria(doc1,doc2, userCriteria)) {
              Pair<Document> p = new Pair(doc1,doc2);
               if(!matches.contains(p)){
                 matches.add(p);
               }
             }
           }
          } 
        }  
     }
```

How can I do this using Streams?

Comment: I won´t sacrifice conciseness and simplicity for the sake of a hard-to-read one-liner, unless you have good reason to do so. Your code seems pretty straight-forwads to me. Or is this just for leraning?

Comment: Btw.: you´re iterating the same list on both loops. Is this intentional?

Comment: He is comparing one ducument to the others, so it is probably intentional

Comment: there is a big performance issue here. you check for A similar to B and B similar to A. yes you skip A=A but. this should be done with indices `i`-> 0..size-1 and `j`-> `i` .. size. you could use . intStream and map to the object, but there are better candidates for steams.

Comment: Yes, because there a different documents in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the following solution using [`Steam::reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) is simple:

1. Group the qualified pairs of documents to `Map<Document, List<Document>>` having all possible acceptable combinations. Let's say odd and even documents are in pairs:

   ```
   D1=[D3, D5], D2=[D4], D3=[D1, D5], D4=[D2], D5[D1, D3]  // dont mind the duplicates
   ```
2. Using `Stream::reduce` you can achieve the following steps:

   - Transform entries to `Pair<>`,

     ```
     D1-D3, D1-D5, D2-D4, D3-D1, D1-D5, D4-D2, D5-D1, D5-D3
     ```
   - Save these items to `Set` guaranteeing the equal pairs occur once (`D1-D3` = `D3-D1`). The condition the `Pair` must override both `Object::equals` and `Object:hashCode` and implements equality based on the both documents present.

     ```
     D1-D3, D1-D5, D3-D5, D2-D4
     ```
   - Reducing (merging) the particular sets into a single collection `Set<Pair<Document>>`.

```
Map<Document, List<Document>> map = documents.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(                                // Collected to Map<Document, List<Document>>
        Function.identity(),                                  // Document is the key
        d1 -> documents.stream()                              // Value are the qualified documents
            .filter(d2 -> !d1.equals(d2) &&            
                utils.matchesOnCriteria(d1,d2, userCriteria)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())));                  // ... as List<Document>

Set<Pair<Document>> matches = map.entrySet().stream().reduce( // Reduce the Entry<Dokument, List<Document>>
    new HashSet<>(),                                          // ... to Set<Pair<>>
    (set, e) -> {
        set.addAll(e.getValue().stream()                      // ... where is
            .map(v -> new Pair<Document>(e.getKey(), v))      // ... the Pair of qualified documents
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));                   
        return set;
    },
    (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; });   // Merge operation
```

The condition `!matches.contains(p)` is redundant, there are better ways to assure distinct values. Either use [`Stream::distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) or collect the stream to `Set` which is an unordered distinct collection.

Read more at [Baeldung's: remove all duplicates](https://www.baeldung.com/java-remove-duplicates-from-list).

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciated!